# Who can access a file with octal permissions "000" on Linux/UNIX?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

If a file has permissions `000`, who or what can access the file? What can they do to it?

What, exactly, does `000 (---------)` permissions on a file mean in practice?

Answer (score 27):

root can do everything, others (with userid != 0) can't do anything. But anyone who has write access to the containing folder is allowed to delete the file.
The owner can of course always change the flags and regain access anytime.

```
greybox:~ septi$ touch foo
greybox:~ septi$ chmod 000 foo
greybox:~ septi$ ls -l foo
----------  1 septi  staff  0 Apr  8 12:28 foo
greybox:~ septi$ cat foo
cat: foo: Permission denied
greybox:~ septi$ sudo ls -l foo
Password:
----------  1 septi  staff  0 Apr  8 12:28 foo
greybox:~ septi$
```

Comment: Isn't file removal governed by the write permission of the directory the file is in? i.e. couldn't anybody with write permissions to the directory remove the file?

Comment: Yes you're right, basically it depends on the containing folder premissions.

Comment: "But anyone who has write access to the containing folder is allowed to delete the file." This is not true.

Comment: You have to explain to me the difference between "write access to the containing folder" and "write permission of the directory the file is in". Sounds just to same to my ears.

Comment: *others (with userid != 0) can't do anything* – **not really true** as the owner of the file can still change its permissions and regain access.

Comment: Yep of course, I added that since the "can't do anything" is indeed a bit misleading ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

File with 000 permission **can** be *read* / *written* by **root**.

Everybody else **cannot** *read* / *write* / *execute* the file.

Comment: What about executing the file?

Comment: on centOS 7, I can read file with 000 permission by "root" user... BUT I COULD NOT WRITE or execute in the file

Comment: So it's the same like 600... Right?

Answer (score 6):

Root can do anything but execute the file (outside removing the file if the file-system is mounted read-only or the file has some immutable flag set).

Non root users might change the file permission if they own it. They can still access the file if ACLs are set to allow it.

Comment: The only answer so far which mentions that the owner of the file can still change its permissions again, restoring access. One useful application is to prevent a webserver from delivering a file in the "trash" while retaining the ability to restore that access later.

Answer (score 6):

Everyone is accurate above unless it is the following command.

```
    sudo chmod -R 000 /*
```

At this point, your computer is dead in the water because no commands can be executed since you have removed all RWX from every file.  There is no safeguard when running this command. If you are curious run it inside a Vagrant box.

Comment: The OS is dead but neither the computer nor the file system are.

Answer (score 5):

If file/dir has permissions 000, then only root can do any changes to that file. Neither the  owner nor others can make any changes. Owner can't even access the file/dir or delete the same.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - the owner of a file can change its permissions even if the mode is set to 000.

Answer (score 2):

Permission can be `XYZ` in which first `X` is for Owner, second `Y` is for
Group (a group of other users that you set up), third `Z` is for
World (anyone else browsing around on the file system). They can have any of following
permissions level:

```
0 = no permissions whatsoever; this person cannot read, write, or execute the file
1 = execute only
2 = write only
3 = write and execute (1+2)
4 = read only
5 = read and execute (4+1)
6 = read and write (4+2)
7 = read and write and execute (4+2+1)
```

So in your example: File with `000` permission can be accessible [read/write] by root. Other than that no one can access[read/write] it.

Answer (score 1):

1. As root, change the permissions of a file to 000.
   This file and its contents can only be accessed by root.
2. As a user, change the permissions of your own file.
   The file and its contents cannot be accessed by the user.
   But the root has full privileges on the file.

Answer (score 1):

I love you all but ...

```
**root**@bob:~# ls -lah /etc/cron.hourly/                                                                                                                       
total 24K  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jun 16 05:23 .  
drwxr-xr-x 110 root root  12K Aug 25 21:26 ..  
**----------   1 root root  228 Aug 25 21:47 gcc.sh**  
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  102 Jun 11  2015 .placeholder  
**root**@bob:~# rm -Rf /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh  
**rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh’: Operation not permitted**
```

so to remove this file (which is a trojan)
I did :

```
root@bob:~# lsattr /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh  
-----a---------- /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh  
root@bob:~# **chattr -a /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh**  
root@bob:~# lsattr /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh  
---------------- /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh
```

then

```
rm -Rf /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh
```

was working

Comment: That's true. The "append" bit prevents (among other things) the file from being erased, regardless of the directory permissions.

Comment: Oh man! Was stuck on this issue for hours! Of all the blog posts, forum threads, only your steps worked to remove the file. I would give a 100 upvotes if I could! Thank you!