# java walkFileTree to mimic chmod -R 755 does not work

Tags: java

I want to ensure correct permissions in a directory tree (0755 for directories and 644 for files). Here is my class:

```
package NRF_Utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions;

public class DirectoryTreeOperations {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("spv." + DirectoryTreeOperations.class.getName());

    public static boolean setPermissions(String root, String directoryPermissions, String filePermissions) {
        boolean result = true;
        //declaring the path to delete
        final Path path = Paths.get(root);
        final Set<PosixFilePermission> dirPermissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString(directoryPermissions);
        final Set<PosixFilePermission> filPermissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString(filePermissions);

        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(path, new FileVisitor<Path>() {

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                        BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("setting dir permission on " + dir);
                    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(dir, dirPermissions);                 
                    return CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                        BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("setting file permission on " + file);
                    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file, filPermissions);
                    return CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc)
                        throws IOException {
                    log.severe("visitFileFailed failed on " + file + " : " + exc);
                    return CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                        IOException exc) throws IOException {
                    return CONTINUE;
                }

            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.severe("setPermissions failed " + e);
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // TODO remove and provide a proper unit test
    public static void main(String [] arg) {
        System.out.println ("setPermissions returned: " + setPermissions("/tmp/x", "rwxr-xr-x", "rw-r--r--"));
    }
}
```

To perform test, I have done:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/x/y/z;touch /tmp/x/y/z/f;chmod 000 /tmp/x/y/z
```

The output is:

```
setting dir permission on /tmp/x
setting dir permission on /tmp/x/y
setPermissions returned: true
nov. 26, 2017 2:45:00 PM NRF_Utils.DirectoryTreeOperations$1 visitFileFailed
GRAVE: visitFileFailed failed on /tmp/x/y/z : java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /tmp/x/y/z
```

It seems java does not want to explore the directory tree because the permissions are wrong, but my aim was to explore the directory tree to fix permissions. Is the API crazy ?

Comment: chmod 000 means no read/write access at all. That is why it is correctly failing with `AccessDeniedException`. Running your code as 'root' user may work!

Comment: chmod -R 755 works perfectly as a user. No need for root.

Comment: For information, it works as root. I do not understand why it is so difficult to replace the shell command chmod -R with native java code. I just want to avoid calling a script.

Comment: `chmod 000 file` makes the file inaccessible to anybody but root. 
please also mind that the actual permissions on the file are more than just the POSIX thre octal numbers.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593752/who-can-access-a-file-with-octal-permissions-000-on-linux-unix

Comment: @BOC what operating system is this?

Comment: OS is RHEL 6, but I have the same behaviour in RHEL 7 and ubuntu. All I want it to have a simple native java way to replace some trivial shell commands.

Answer (score 5):

It does seem strange it would behave this way, so maybe not a crazy API, but the implementation certainly doesn't cater to the specific case of using preVisitDirectory() to make the directory accessible.

The `Files.walkFileTree()` doc says:

> Where the file is a directory, and the directory could not be opened,
>   then the visitFileFailed method is invoked with the I/O exception,
>   after which, the file tree walk continues, by default, at the next
>   sibling of the directory.

and looking at the implementation, it does actually try to open the directory before it calls `visitor.preVisitDirectory()` which explains the issue you are running into.

As a solution, you could grab the FileTreeWalker.java source, and make the minor adjustment in your own local version of the FileTreeWalker - it's straight forward just look for the call to `visitor.preVisitDirectory()` and move the open directory code to occur after that.  Then change your code to:

```
  new FileTreeWalker(EnumSet.noneOf(FileVisitOption.class), new FileVisitor<Path>() {
     ...
  }, Integer.MAX_VALUE).walk(path);
```

When you run, you'll get:

```
setting dir permission on /tmp/x
setting dir permission on /tmp/x/y
setting dir permission on /tmp/x/y/z
setting file permission on /tmp/x/y/z/f
setPermissions returned: true
```

which shows your of implementation of `FileVisitor` is fine.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `chmod 755 /tmp/x/y/z` from the command line, it does not check the permission on `z` itself. As long as you have sufficient access to `y`, you can perform `chmod` on `z`.

OTOH, if you look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/nio/file/Files.java#Files.walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path%2Cjava.util.Set%2Cint%2Cjava.nio.file.FileVisitor%29) of `Files.walkFileTree`, it actually tries to access every target file in its own `visit` method, to gather file attributes etc., **before** it calls your visitor methods. Hence the access denied error.

By the look of it, you might have to roll your own file tree walker, where you would just go ahead change the permission without trying to access the target path first.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with `walkFileTree` is that it doesn't call `preVisitDirectory()` on directories it doesn't have permission to search.  You can work around that by fixing the permissions just ahead of where walkFileTree is looking. 
 I.e., by manually scanning the direct children of any directory handed to `preVisitDirectoy()` and applying permissions there (rather than in `visitFile`):

```
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                for(File f : new File(dir.toUri()).listFiles()) { //iterate over the contents of the directory
                    System.out.println("setting dir permission on " + f);
                    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(dir.resolve(f.getName()), dirPermissions);
                }

                //System.out.println("setting dir permission on " + dir);
                //Files.setPosixFilePermissions(dir, dirPermissions);
                return CONTINUE;
            }
```

Then you can comment out `visitFile()`'s body:

```
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            //    System.out.println("setting file permission on " + file);
            //    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file, filPermissions);
                return CONTINUE;
            }
```

Since we're now applying permissions one layer below where the walk has made it to, we need an additional call just inside the try block:

```
        System.out.println("setting dir permission on " + path); //in case the initial path needs fixing
        Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, dirPermissions);
```

Here's the whole thing together (well, I took off your package declaration for convenience):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions;

public class DirectoryTreeOperations {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("spv." + DirectoryTreeOperations.class.getName());

    public static boolean setPermissions(String root, String directoryPermissions, String filePermissions) {
        boolean result = true;
        //declaring the path to delete
        final Path path = Paths.get(root);
        final Set<PosixFilePermission> dirPermissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString(directoryPermissions);
        final Set<PosixFilePermission> filPermissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString(filePermissions);

        try {
            System.out.println("setting dir permission on " + path); //in case the initial path needs fixing
            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, dirPermissions);

            Files.walkFileTree(path, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                        BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    for(File f : new File(dir.toUri()).listFiles()) { //iterate over the contents of the directory
                        System.out.println("setting dir permission on " + f);
                        Files.setPosixFilePermissions(dir.resolve(f.getName()), dirPermissions);
                    }

                    //System.out.println("setting dir permission on " + dir);
                    //Files.setPosixFilePermissions(dir, dirPermissions);
                    return CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                        BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                //    System.out.println("setting file permission on " + file);
                //    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file, filPermissions);
                    return CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc)
                        throws IOException {
                    log.severe("visitFileFailed failed on " + file + " : " + exc);
                    return CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                        IOException exc) throws IOException {
                    return CONTINUE;
                }

            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.severe("setPermissions failed " + e);
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // TODO remove and provide a proper unit test
    public static void main(String [] arg) {
        System.out.println ("setPermissions returned: " + setPermissions("/tmp/x", "rwxr-xr-x", "rw-r--r--"));
    }
}
```

When run on the example case:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/x/y/z;touch /tmp/x/y/z/f;chmod 000 /tmp/x/y/z
$ find /tmp/x
/tmp/x
/tmp/x/y
/tmp/x/y/z
find: â/tmp/x/y/zâ: Permission denied
$ java DirectoryTreeOperations
setting dir permission on /tmp/x
setting dir permission on /tmp/x/y
setting dir permission on /tmp/x/y/z
setting dir permission on /tmp/x/y/z/f
setPermissions returned: true
$ find /tmp/x
/tmp/x
/tmp/x/y
/tmp/x/y/z
/tmp/x/y/z/f
```